# React router pass specific params to child compents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a perplexing problem that I cant figure out. I am new to react + flux + react router.

I have the following routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Search}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route name="client" path="/client(/:clientid)" component={Client}/>
        {/* <Route name="tel" path="/tel/:telid" component={Tel}/>*/}
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I want to be able to pass specific params to specific routes. I know i can pass all params to all routes using:

```
{this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...})}
```

however I dont want to allow sub components access to other component states. Ideally I'd like to pass the loginState to the login component, the searchState to the search component and the clientState to the client component. with the above method the client component can access all component states.

I currently have this workaround but it feels dirty and not very future proof:

```
var React = require('react');

var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');

var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

// Flux cart view
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return AppStore.getState();
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.state.auth.loggedIn) {
            browserHistory.push('/login');
        }
    },
    // Add change listeners to stores
    componentDidMount() {
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    // Remove change listers from stores
    componentWillUnmount() {
        AppStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    // Method to setState based upon Store changes
    _onChange(){
        this.setState(AppStore.getState());
    },

  // Render cart view
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    var name = this.props.children.type.displayName;
    var p;
    switch(name) {
        case 'client':
            p = {clientState: 'test'}
        break;
        case 'login':
            p = {auth: this.state.auth}
        break;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, p)}
        </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = App;
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this correctly? I have looked at a lot of google results but most harken back to the old versions of react and react-router.

Comment: I hope, what you're after is [createElement](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props) of `Router` component

Comment: @code-jaff thanks for that - being new how would i implement that? is it in the main App controller (main route) and i presume its a case of simply overriding that function? could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [named components](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#named-components)

```
...     
<Route path="/login" components={{login:Login}} />
<Route path="/client(/:clientid)" components={{client:Client}}/>
...
```

And in App component

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.setProps= this.setProps.bind(this);
    }
    setProps(comp, props){
        if(!comp) return null;
        return React.cloneElement(comp, props);
    }
    render(){
        const {client, login}=this.props;
        const {clientData, loginData}=this.state;

        return (<div>
            {this.setProps(client,clientData)}
            {this.setProps(login,loginData)}
        </div>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

it also usefull when on page more then one component per route

Comment: had to alter some items so as to pass the data over inside an object and convert to module not ES6 but thanks - all working as expected.